# How to move a MySQL select result into a physical file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I used

```
select * from table into outfile "C:\\1.txt"
```

it always failed with the error:

> there is something wrong near "into"

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL docs:

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' form of SELECT writes the
>   selected rows to a file. The file is created on the server host, so
>   you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. file_name cannot
>   be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as
>   /etc/passwd and database tables from being destroyed. The
>   character_set_filesystem system variable controls the interpretation
>   of the file name.
>
> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement is intended primarily to let you
>   very quickly dump a table to a text file on the server machine. If you
>   want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server
>   host, you normally cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is
>   no way to write a path to the file relative to the server host's file
>   system.

So you would want to do something like this:

```
SELECT a,b,c INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt' FROM table;
```

Instead of

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt';
```

Comment: I tred 'SELECT a,b,c FROM table INTO OUTFILE 'C:\result.txt'; But it still doesn't work. it returned the same error message;And the database is in Windows Server2003, and i don't know if I have the file privilege...

Comment: Please read what I said. Use 'SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE 'file' FROM table; 

Instead of:
SELECT .. FROM table INTO OUTFILE 'file';

Comment: OK. now, "SELECT id INTO OUTFILE "E:\\result.txt" FROM table;" it says "there's something wrong near 'E:\result.txt' ",Does that mean I don't have the file privilege, or I wrote the path in a wrong way?